# Is there any way I can separate the stacks of the contexts I get from getcontext()?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, address-space

Is there any way I can separate the stacks of the context I get from getcontext()? Such that it is exact copy of parent with a different stack. So that when I use setcontext()  or swapcontext() it would essentially work like a fork system call?

I want to be able to use it even after the calling function returns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `uc_mcontext` in the `ucontext`. It contains an array of registers one of them is the ESP register for 32bit machines. Which is the stack pointer of that context.